# How to measure CPU and memory during load test

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, load-testing, webapplicationstresstool

We are using JMeter in a heterogeneous environment and we would like to measure CPU and memory while we are producing heavy load on a server where our service or web application is running. What would you recommend to use? Is there any software solution (open source or commercial) available which records CPU and memory usage in a file or to a database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the java perspective, you can use [jconsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) or write your own [code](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/determining_memory_usage_in_java.shtml) to monitor the memory usage.

1. [Measure CPU and memory consumption of a Java application](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/measure-cpu-and-memory-consumption-of-a-java-application/#.)
2. [javasysmon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon) on github
3. [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) for linux and perfmon for windows. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345543/perfmon-like-for-linux)

Comment: Thank you!! Great answer! I'm looking currently at jconsole and javasysmon. It would be great if there is a tool which runs as a service and records CPU and memory usage of an application doesn't matter if its a java or native application.

Comment: I meant, is the OP looking for a "a tool which runs as a service and records CPU and memory usage" for any particular OS?

Comment: if possible. and we are also looking for a tool which capture the usage of the whole computer system while running a load test.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [our JMeter perfmon plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) to measure CPU, memory [and a lot of other metrics](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/):

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at PerfMon.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).

It could collect resource usages like CPU, MEM easily with built-in templates and display them in nice graphics. Both Windows and Uni* are supported.

Answer (score 0):

One you install the Perfmon plugin, I also had to install the server agent, and open the firewall port 4444.

Here's a link which I found super useful.

http://grosan.co.uk/web-application-performance-testing-using-apache-jmeter-part-2-monitor-server-resources/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take a look to [collectd](https://collectd.org/) if you run in some unix/linux flavour. It will bring you not only CPU but also memory, Disk IO, network and a good number of plugins available.