# How can we judge an application( For eg: the application is 90%/80% Good , Application is poor Performance) using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can we judge an application( For eg: the application is 90%/80% Good ,
 Application is poor Performance) using Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

Objective of jmeter is to validate the question "How much load can server handle at a instance" for that purpose you can use :

1) Listeners basically Graph Result which will clear measurement of your website performance.

2) Apart from that you can get the CPU usage and other factors for your servers.

Please go through the following :
[Terminologies used for measurement of performance](http://jmeterperftest.blogspot.in/)

[CPU UTILIZATION CALCULATION USING JMETER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192722/how-to-measure-cpu-and-memory-during-load-test/)

[Ultimate Thread Group](http://testingfreak.com/tools/jmeter/ultimate-thread-group/)